# How to resize img inside div border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a banner for my html file ( with links overlaying it) but I can't get the img to resize itself into the div border. It keeps going outside of the border and overflow: hidden; just cuts it off. 
Here is my code below:-

```css
    <style>
        img
        {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;     
        }
        .topdiv
        {
            height: 250px;
            border: 4px solid black;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden; 
        }
    
        
        .banner
        {
            float: left;
        }
        .banlink
        {
            float: right;
            float: bottom;
            border: 4px solid black;
        }
        
        .topdiv .banlink nav a 
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #295c87;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="topdiv">
            
            <div class="banner">
                
                <img src="thedry.png" title="[]_[]" alt="deck" style="width: 100%;"/> 
        
            </div>
            
            <div class="banlink">
            
                <nav>
                    <!-- style="text-decoration: none;" --> 
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    
                    <a href="page2.html">Pictures</a>
                    
                    <a href="page3.html">Meet the Family</a>
                 </nav>
            
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/hu8bf3m3/

Comment: This CSS is invalid: `float: bottom;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image banner width and height to 100%(or the percentage you prefer) of the width and height of the banner div, in this way it doesn't overflow.
Pay attention to set the correct percentage in order to maintain proportion of your image.
Also, you can set your image as **background-image** of banner div, but also in this case maybe your image may result stretched.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are trying to do --

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/v1SabYdIlZI/maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px 100px;
}

.topdiv {
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.banlink {
  float: right;
  float: bottom;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.topdiv .banlink nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #295c87;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="topdiv">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="banlink">
        <nav>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="page2.html">Pictures</a>
          <a href="page3.html">Meet the Family</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```